# Downloading the Geoserver SQL Server Extension

Tags: geoserver, sql-server

I have successfully installed GeoServer on a 64 bit Windows Server and would like to install the Geoserver SQL Server Extension so that I can hook GeoServer up to SQL Server 2017.

The GeoServer instructions at http://docs.geoserver.org/stable/en/user/data/database/sqlserver.html say that I can download the extension from http://geoserver.org/download/ but I can't see the extension listed there.

Does anyone know from where I can download the extension?

Comment: I have the same problem with it :)
Links gaved below are broken or i can not connect, says 'This site can’t be reached build.geoserver.org took too long to respond."
Please help .. I found it here http://geoserver.org/release/stable/
you must choose the version of geoserver and scroll down to Extensions
[![enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/M4Lv3.jpg)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/M4Lv3.jpg)

Comment: as of today build.geoserver.org is down, please join the user-list for updates

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can [grab it from this site](https://build.geoserver.org/geoserver/).

Navigate through by selecting the version of GeoServer you're on, and get the latest for that version. So, for version 2.13, you can get it here: `https://build.geoserver.org/geoserver/2.13.x/ext-latest/` and the URL is this one: https://build.geoserver.org/geoserver/2.13.x/ext-latest/geoserver-2.13-SNAPSHOT-sqlserver-plugin.zip

Comment: Many, many thanks for that answer Alex. Very useful.